# Accessing non-const data members from constexpr member function

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, constexpr

Both GCC and MSVC seem to allow defining constexpr accessor functions for non-const data members:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    int val;

public:
    Foo(int v) : val(v) {}

    constexpr int get_val() { return val; } // OK
};

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    Foo foo((int)rd());
    std::cout << foo.get_val(); // works
}
```

Is this nonstandard behavior from MSVC and GCC or does the standard actually allow this?

Comment: `constexpr` doesn't _require_ a function to be evaluated at compile time. It's more `constexpr`-preserving--if the inputs are constant expressions, the output is also a constant expression. In this case it means you can call `get_val` on a `constexpr Foo`, but nothing stops you from calling it at other times. (Actually, this particular function couldn't be called on a `constexpr Foo` unless it was both `constexpr` and `const`, but you could call it in a `constexpr` context.)

Comment: interesting, so the constexpr requirement is more that it must be *possible* to evaluate at compile time given appropriate inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this is allowed! `constexpr` don't mean `const`. You can even mutate values in a `constexpr` function:

```
class Foo
{
    int val;

public:
    constexpr Foo(int v) : val(v) {} // OK

    constexpr int get_val() { return val; } // OK
    constexpr void set_val(int v) { val = v; } // OK
};
```

With this you can write constexpr functions that look like normal function, it's just that they may be executed at compile time in the compiler runtime.

```
constexpr int test() {
    Foo f{};

    f.set_val(2);

    return f.get_val();
}

static_assert(test() == 2); // Checks at compile time
```